# How to implement a good moving average in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing, moving-average

I'm doing some research and I'm implementing a moving average in Python based on this mathematical expression:

[image: Moving Average for Peak Detection]
Where: n = sample and W1 = Window

I implemented like that:

```
def movingAverage(signal, window):

   sum = 0
   mAver = []
   k = int((window-1)/2)

   for i in np.arange(k, len(signal)-k):
       for ii in np.arange(i-k, i+k):
           sum = sum + signal[ii]
       #end-for
       mAver.append(sum / window)
       sum = 0
   #end-for

   zeros = [0]*k
   mAver = zeros + mAver + zeros

   return mAver
```

It work very well. But I'm trying to discover some way to implement the `k` variant to minimize the signal lost in beginning and in final (Now I'm using an list with zeros).

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use Pandas and specify `center=True` for your moving average.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(7)).round(1)
moving_avg = s.rolling(window=3).mean(center=True)
>>> pd.concat([s, moving_avg.round(2)], axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'signal', 1: 'MA'})
   signal    MA
0     1.8   NaN
1     0.4  1.07  # 1.07 = (1.8 + 0.4 + 1.0) / 3
2     1.0  1.20  # 1.20 = (0.4 + 1.0 + 2.2) / 3
3     2.2  1.70
4     1.9  1.03
5    -1.0  0.63
6     1.0   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to implement it without using libraries.
It can be good to implement in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filter with taps of all 1

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.signal as sig

h = sp.ones(10)/10
y = sig.lfilter(h, 1, x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to implement it without using libraries.
It can be good to implement in other languages.

Comment: It looks like you are already using numpy.  Scipy includes numpy with additional packages thrown in for various signal and numeric prcessing functions.

Comment: If you want to implement the moving average this way, you have to set `a` to the length of `b`, so the window sum is divided and the result is the average, otherwise you end up multiplying the input by the window length.

Comment: I have just made the edit. You can plot the previous version vs. the corrected one to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I have found the following code:

```
def moving_average(samples, wind_len=1000):
    wind_len = int(wind_len)
    cumsum_samples = np.cumsum(samples)
    cumsum_diff = cumsum_samples[wind_len:] - cumsum_samples[:-wind_len]
    samples_average = cumsum_diff / float(wind_len)
    return samples_average

def my_cumsum(samples):
    for ind in range(1, len(samples)):
       samples[ind] = samples[ind] + samples[ind - 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to implement it without using libraries.
It can be good to implement in other languages.